# Find an object stored in std::vector by comparing string to object's variable

Tags: c++

I have a vector that stores objects of class IdKaart.

```
std::vector<IdCard *> IdCard_vect;
```

Below the class definition:

```
#ifndef IDCARD_H
#define IDCARD_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Lock;


class IdCard {

public:
    IdCard(string, string, string);
    string userId();
    void giveAccess(Lock*);
    void removeAccess(Lock*);
    bool hasAccess(Lock*);

private:
    string id;
    vector<Lock*> access;
    string name, adress;
};

#endif // IDCARD_H
```

I need to be able to find an object in above vector by comparing a string with "id". Considering this id is private, member function "userId()" is used to return this string.

When above object is found, I need to be able to call the giveAccess(Lock *) function.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: you want `std::find` with a lambda/functor.

Comment: `std::find_if` comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::string idToFind = …;
auto it = std::find_if(IdCard_vect.begin(), IdCard_vect.end(),
                       [&](IdCard* card) { return card->userId() == idToFind; });
if (it != IdCard_vect.end()) {
    // card was found, can be accessed with `*it`.
}
```

or a good old for-if:

```
IdCard* result = nullptr;
for (IdCard* card : IdCard_vect)
    if (card->userId() == idToFind)
        result = card;
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't/don't want to use lambdas, you can create a custom predicate functor:

```
struct pointerIdCompare : public std::unary_function<IdCard*, bool>
{
  pointerIdCompare(const std::string &id) : _id(id) {}

  bool operator() (const IdCard* idCard)
  { return idCard->userId() == _id; }

  std::string _id;
};
```

And then use it in `find_if` to get an iterator:

```
std::vector<IdCard*>::const_iterator cIt = std::find_if(IdCard_vect.begin(), IdCard_vect.end(), pointerIdCompare("some-id"));
```

You then use this iterator to call `giveAccess`:

```
if ( cIt != IdCard_vect.end() )
{
    (*cIt)->giveAccess(...);
}
```